# Writing a complex matrix to a file in Fortran

Tags: fortran

How does one write a **complex** (n×n) matrix in Fortran to a file? 
For example:

```
DO I=1,N
       write(14,'(100g15.5)') ( M(i,j), j=1,n )
ENDDO
```

In this example one gets 2n×n elements written to the file i.e. the real and imaginary.
Instead of two element, Re(a11) Im(a11), How can I  write it as one element Re(a11)+iIm(a11)?

Answer (score 5):

Use intrinsic functions REAL and AIMAG to write individual real and imaginary components of a complex number:

```
CHARACTER(LEN=3),DIMENSION(n,n) :: imag_unit = '+i*'

WHERE(AIMAG(M)<0.)imag_unit = '-i*'

DO I=1,N
  write(14,'(100(g15.5,a,g15.5,2x))') ( REAL(M(i,j)),imag_unit(i,j),&
                                        ABS(AIMAG(M(i,j))), j=1,n )
ENDDO
```

Explanation: This code defines a matrix of character strings that have value '+i' when imaginary part is positive, and '-i' where imaginary part is negative. Because the negative imaginary part is accounted for in the formatting ('-i'), we take absolute value of the imaginary part. Edit the format descriptor accordingly so that the program you use to read the output file will be able to read it.

Comment: HI IRO-bot,
below is the output file and as you see its not OK:
5.4585    +i    -7.2662          -7.6987    +i     6.7328           6.4439    +i     4.7736           4.4043    +i    -7.7265

Comment: I would like it to be readable for Matalb, i.e that Matlab will understand that it is nXn complex matrix

Comment: I have no idea what Matlab likes to see. Can you edit your question with a formatting example?

Comment: yes I see your edited answer. unfortunately I didn't understand it :(