# fortran format specifier for complex number

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

Can I specify a format specifier for a complex number in fortran? I have a simple program.

```
program complx1
implicit none
complex :: var1
var1 = (10,20)
write (*,*) var1
write (*,'(F0.0)') var1
write (*,'(F0.0,A,F0.0)') real(var1), ' + i ' , aimag(var1)
end program complx1
```

Output:

```
 (  10.0000000    ,  20.0000000    )
10.
20.
10. + i 20.
```

I wanted to use inbuilt format for `a+bi` with some format specifier, instead of one did manually (second last line of program). Obviously `F0.0` did not work. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I don't think this is a duplicate of post: [writing complex matrix in fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717223/writing-complex-matrix-in-fortran), which says to use `REAL` and `AIMAG` functions. I already used those functions and wondering whether there is an inbuilt format that can do the work.

Comment: Does an inbuilt format exist or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [writing complex matrix in fortran](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717223/writing-complex-matrix-in-fortran)

Comment: @francescalus, I don't think this is a duplicate. Please see edit part in question

Comment: That other answer suggests that approach because there is no "natural" other way.  I've undeleted (and improved) my answer (from before I found that other question - perversely because I made exactly the same mistake...) which hopefully explains why.  [Also, I think this is a better question, so I'll leave it there in case others think the duplicate should go the other way.  Or delete again if there's consensus I should.]

Answer (score 10):

An addendum to @francescalus' existing, and mostly satisfactory, answer.  A format string such as

```
fmt = '(F0.0,SP,F0.0,"i")'
```

should result in a complex number being displayed with the correct sign between real and imaginary parts; no need to fiddle around with strings to get a plus sign in there.

Answer (score 4):

There is no distinct complex edit descriptor.  In Fortran 2008, 10.7.2.3.6 we see

> A complex datum consists of a pair of separate real data. The editing of a scalar datum of complex type is specified by two edit descriptors each of which specifies the editing of real data.

In your second example, which you say "did not work", you see this formatting in action.  Because the format had only one descriptor with no repeat count the values are output in distinct records (format reversion).

The first of your three cases is a very special one: it uses list-directed output.  The rules for the output are

> Complex constants are enclosed in parentheses with a separator between the real and imaginary parts

There is another useful part of the first rule mentioned:

> Control and character string edit descriptors may be processed between the edit descriptor for the real part and the edit descriptor for the imaginary part.

You could happily adapt your second attempt, as we note that your "not working" wasn't because of the use of the complex variable itself (rather than the real and imaginary components)

```
write (*, '(F0.0,"+i",F0.0)') var1
```

This, though, isn't right when you have potentially negative complex part.  You'll need to change the sign in the middle.  This is possible, using a character variable format (rather than literal) with a conditional, but it perhaps isn't worth the effort.  See [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8717795) for details of another approach, similar to your third option but more robust.

Another option is to write a function which returns a correctly written character representation of your complex variable.  That's like your third option.  It is also the least messy approach when you want to write out many complex variables.

Finally, if you do have to worry about negative complex parts but want a simple specification of the variable list, there is the truly ugly

```
write(*,'(F0.0,"+i*(",F0.0,")")') var1
```

or the imaginative

```
character(19) fmt
fmt = '(F0.0,"+",F0.0,"i")'
fmt(8:8) = MERGE('+',' ',var1%im.gt.0)
write(*,fmt) var1
```

or the even better use of the `SP` control edit descriptor as given by [High Performance Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30301088) which temporarily (for the duration of the output statement) sets the sign mode of the transfer to `PLUS` which forces the printing of the otherwise optional "+" sign.  [Alternatively, this can be set for the connection itself in an `open` with the `sign='plus'` specifier.]

All this is because the simple answer is: no, there is no in-built complex edit descriptor.