# Format specifier for a complex matrix

Tags: formatting, fortran

I already read about the format specifier for complex numbers in here [fortran format specifier for complex number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291333/fortran-format-specifier-for-complex-number)

However I was not able to modify it to my wishes. I have double complex matrix of known dimension and I want it to be written like this:

```
{1.000E+00, 0.000E+00} {2.123E+00, 6.545E+20} {5.456E+24, 5.562E+12} ....
{1.000E+00, 0.000E+00} {2.123E+00, 6.545E+20} {5.456E+24, 5.562E+12}
{1.000E+00, 0.000E+00} {2.123E+00, 6.545E+20} {5.456E+24, 5.562E+12}
...
```

So the first part in the curly brackets should be the real part and the second part the imaginary part. The matrix elements should be in curly brackets each and placed next to each other according to the position in the matrix.

So far I could just print out one element correctly or all matrix elements under each other with the following format: `("{",ES10.3, ",", 1X, ES10.3 ,"}")`

EDIT:

```
program test
  implicit none
  double complex                    ::  zz
  double complex, dimension(3,4)    ::  aa
  character (len=32)                ::  fmtString

  zz = cmplx(1.d0, -2.d0)

  fmtString = '("{",ES10.3, ",", 1X ES10.3,"}")'
  write(0,fmt = fmtString) zz   !works
  write(0,fmt = fmtString)aa    !not formatted propperly
end program test
```

results in something like this, since aa is not initialized:

```
{ 1.000E+00, -2.000E+00}   <- zz works
{ 9.881-324,  9.387-323}   <- aa doesn't since it is not displayed as a 3x4 matrix
{ 6.953-310,  0.000E+00}
{ 0.000E+00,  0.000E+00}
{ 1.812-314,  6.953-310}
{ 0.000E+00,  1.019-312}
{ 0.000E+00,  0.000E+00}
{ 4.496-322,  0.000E+00}
{ 0.000E+00,  2.631-312}
{ 0.000E+00,  2.631-312}
{ 0.000E+00,  1.210-316}
{ 1.210-316,  1.210-316}
{ 1.210-316,  3.953-323}
```

So how do I proceed?

Comment: ... The values doens't matter since it should be a general matrix output subroutine. So the thing that bothers me is the layout of the print. How can I achive, that the values a ordered in row and columns for example like an output in maltab?

Comment: You just need to add a repeat specifier to the format.  There must be a good question here to point you to, but I can't find at the moment.  You may also want to make the repeat count variable (for which there'll be another question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
program test
  implicit none
  double complex                    ::  zz
  double complex, dimension(3,4)    ::  aa
  character (50)                    ::  fmtString
  integer                           ::  i

  zz = cmplx(1.d0, -2.d0)
  aa = zz ! aa needs to be initialized too

  fmtString = '(9999("{",ES10.3,",",1X,ES10.3,"}",:,1X))'

  write(*,fmt = fmtString) zz
  do i=1,size(aa,1)
     write(*,fmt = fmtString) aa(i,:)
  enddo
end program test
```

Comment: Thank you! what is the semicolon doing? 
Also I generalized the 9999 a little bit, since it can occur that one wants to output larger matrices: 
`write(fmtString,'(I0)') size(aa,2) ` and then
`fmtString = '('// trim(fmtString) //'("{",ES10.3, ",", 1X, ES10.3,"}",:,1X))'`

Comment: the semi colon just avoids the last space at the end of each line. (elements after the semicolon are ignored when there is no data to print anymore). Your proposal is of course acceptable but, if your compiler supports it (F2008), just replace my 9999 by the character * (unlimited repetition).